# Interesting circles hidden in Poncelet's porism configuration

Tags: geometry, inversive-geometry

This question is an investigation starting [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854222/on-constructing-a-triangle-given-the-circumradius-inradius-and-altitude/1854236?noredirect=1#comment3797224_1854236), with a straightedge and compass construction of $ABC$ given $(R,r,h_A)$. The key lemma is the following one:

[image]

> Let $\Gamma$ be a circle with centre $O$, radius $R$ and let $A\in\Gamma$. Let $H_A$ be any point inside $\Gamma$ such that $AH_A=h_A$ and let $B',C'$ be the intersections between $\Gamma$ and the perpendicular to $AH_A$ through $H_A$. **Claim:** the incenter $I'$ of $AB'C'$ lies on a circle.

I was able to prove the above claim by trigonometry, but I am not satisfied by my solution and I strongly believe that more elegant ones exists. There are many interesting facts in the above configuration:

- $bc=AB'\cdot AC' = 2 h_A R$ is constant;
- $OI'^2=R^2-2Rr$ is fixed too, by Euler's theorem;
- $I'$ lies on the angle bisector of $\widehat{H_A A O}$ since the circumcenter $O$
   and the orthocenter $H$ are isogonal conjugates;
- By Carnot's theorem, the sum of the distances of $O$ from the sides of $ABC$ equals $R+r$;
- $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{h_A}+\frac{1}{h_B}+\frac{1}{h_C} = \frac{1}{h_A}\left(1+\frac{b+c}{a}\right);$
- the circumradius of the nine point circle equals $\frac{R}{2}$ and by Feuerbach's theorem
   the circumcircle of the medial/orthic triangle is tangent to the incircle.

**Update:** solved with an elementary proof in my own answer.

An equivalent formulation comes from considering the [Poncelet's porism](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PonceletsPorism.html) configuration.
 The set of triangles with given inradius and circumradius is given by the case $n=3$:

[image]

> In this configuration, if we take $A'$ on the $OA$ ray in such a way that $AA'=AH_A$,
>  then both $A'$ and the orthocenter $H$ lie on fixed circles.

Are you able to provide a simple proof of the last claim?

**Update:** $H\in\text{circle}$ is solved with an elementary proof in my own answer.
 We just need to find an elementary proof of $A'\in\text{circle}$.

I give an extra picture for clarity: clearly, the purple circles we are interested in are fixed by the two isosceles triangles having the given inradius and circumradius.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let we start from the second question, second part.

If we consider the centre of the nine point circle, $N=\frac{O+H}{2}$, [Feuerbach's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FeuerbachsTheorem.html) gives 
$$ IN = \frac{R}{2}-r, $$
hence $N$ travels on a circle centered at $I$ with a constant radius.
 By homothety, $H$ travels on a circle, too, having radius $R-2r$. Summarizing:

> The orthocenter $H$ of a triangle always lies on a circle having radius $R-2r$ centered at
>  the symmetric of the circumcenter $O$ with respect to the incenter $I$.

In a similar way, assuming that $A'$ actually travels on a circle, the centre of such a circle has to be the symmetric of the incenter $I$ with respect to the circumcenter $O$ (by simply considering the isosceles triangles in Poncelet's configuration). Let we call such a point $J$. About the first part, we just have to prove that
$$ A'J^2 = (R+h_A)^2+(R^2-2Rr)+2(R+h_A)\sqrt{R^2-2Rr} \cos(\widehat{AOI})$$
does not really depend on $h_A$. That is the unpleasant part I cracked through trigonometry:
it boils down to expressing $\frac{b+c}{a}$ in terms of $R,r$ and $h_A$, or expressing $\frac{a}{a+b+c}$ in terms of
 $R,r$ and $h_A$, where:
$$ \frac{a}{a+b+c}=\frac{ar}{r(a+b+c)}=\frac{a r}{2\Delta} = \frac{ar}{ah_A}=\frac{r}{h_A}.$$

---

About the first question, we may consider $I'_A$, the $A$-excenter of the $AB'C'$ triangle. Then $IB' I'_A C'$ is a cyclic quadrilateral with circumcircle $\Gamma_A$, and the claim follows from
$$\text{pow}_A(\Gamma_A) = AI'\cdot AI'_A = f(h_A, R). $$
The [incenter-excenter lemma](http://www.mit.edu/~evanchen/handouts/Fact5/Fact5.pdf) gives that the centre of $\Gamma_A$ is the midpoint $N$ of the minor $B'C'$ arc, hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\text{pow}_A(\Gamma_A) = AN^2 - R_A^2 = AN^2 - MB'^2 &=& 2R^2\left(\cos A+\cos(B-C)\right)\\ &=& 4R^2 \sin B \sin C\\&=& bc = 2Rh_A.\end{eqnarray*}$$

> We may avoid trigonometry at all by just noticing that $\Gamma_A$ is symmetric with respect to the $A$-angle bisector $l_A$, hence $\text{pow}_A(\Gamma_A)=bc=2R h_A$ readily follows by considering the symmetric of $B',C'$ with respect to $l_A$, that still lie on $\Gamma_A$.